# Why does Chrome sometimes need to be restarted for "Choose File" to work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, input

```
<input type="file"/>
```

The dialog to browse/select a file intermittently stops displaying in Chrome. When it stops displaying I see the page border flash when clicking "Choose File". The button works again after restarting Chrome.

When this happens, users think my app is broken. I added a note that if the dialog stops displaying they need to restart their browser, but there has got to be a better solution.

Comment: Judging by the fact that the browser window is flashing it sounds like the dialog is actually displaying *under* the browser window. If that's the case, sounds like Chrome is a little clumsy with window focus.

Comment: Or it could be something else entirely, if the Chrome window can be closed normally (i.e. with the close button, not from the taskbar, or Task Manager).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this happens whenever Chrome requires an update. Restarting chrome automatically installs the update.